# Is there an infinite graph that corresponds to a group which has precisely all finite groups as subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

This is a followup question [to Pavel C's question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997428/is-there-a-group-which-has-precisely-all-finite-groups-as-subgroups) . It's fairly obvious from the axiom of choice that taking the direct sum of all finite groups produces the desired group. At the associated MathOverflow discussion referenced there, Joel David Hamkins noted there are countably infinitely many finite groups, so the resulting group is at most countably infinite. By Frucht's theorem, every finite group is the group of symmetries of a finite undirected graph. More strongly, for any finite group G there exist infinitely many non-isomorphic simple connected graphs such that the automorphism group of each of them is isomorphic to G.

Here's my question: Is there an infinite undirected connected graph which corresponds to the group G constructed above where each of these non-isomorphic simple connected graphs *are subgraphs of this graph-and if so, is this graph at most countably infinite or larger?*

I think this is a great question with some deep implications for algebraic graph theory if it exists.

Of course,if a simple counterexample exists,I end up looking like a schmuck........lol

Comment: How about considering the finite field extensions of  $\mathbb C(t)$? The inverse Galois problem has been solved for this field. Can you pull out a graph out of this? I have no idea if this works, it's just an idea.

Comment: Wow,looks like I finally stumped the board. Maybe I really got a legitimate research question here. Hope I have enough time to solve it and publish before someone beats me to it now that I was dumb enough to blab it to the whole internet........lol

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva  A VERY good idea-I'll try it once I'm done building my website. Anyone else wants to take a stab at it,be my guest!